# SQL Query: sum the values

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a userprofile table:

```
**userid   attr**
jack       swimming
jack       fishing
maria      football
maria      fishing
maria      climbing
```

and a value table for the attributes (the value with the latest date is present)

```
**attr       dateofvalue    value**
swimming     01.07.19       2
swimming     02.03.19       5 
swimming     02.02.19       0,5
fishing      01.05.19       3    
fishing      17.03.19       4
football     02.10.19       1,5
football     05.09.19       6
climbing     12.12.19       4
climbing     11.11.19       2,5
```

I want to have the total value of a given userprofile.
The total value of a userprofile is calculated with the latest values.
For example the total value of the userprofile from **maria = 8,5** (1,5 + 3 + 4)

I already tried this:
select u.userid, sum(a.value)
from userprofile u, attributes a
where u.attr = a.attr and u.userid = 'maria'
group by u.userid;

But this doesn't work correctly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window functions to determine the most recent value and then aggregate:

```
select up.userid, sum(a.value)
from (select a.*,
             row_number() over (partition by attr order by dateofvalue desc) as seqnum
      from attributes a
     ) a join
     userprofiles up
     on a.attr = up.attr and a.seqnum = 1
group by up.userid;
```